# Unity Android app black screen on startup

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, android-app-bundle

When building an apk for Android of my application, the screen remains black, not even showing the "Made with Unity" logo.

On closer inspection, the app is indeed running as intended, but is obscured by a black screen, which does not go away unless I minimize the app and open it again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Adding a [mre] will help people identify why your app is doing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Unity 2022.3.2f1. I found out that it has to do somenthing with "Render outside safe area" in Player settings. When I turn it on, the app is working fine.

I am still finding the "right" solution but it seems to be some kind of bug.. hope it helps if you still have not solved it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34806235)